# How can I get placeholder attribute value using jquery?

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to get the `placeholder` attribute value and do a `fadeIn` with the label which has the `placeholder` value as a `for` value, but it's not working.

**HTML:**

```
<html>  
    <body>
        <form>
            <input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="First Name" />
            <label for="First Name">First Name </label>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

**CSS:**

```
input+label { display: none; }
```

**Script**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input[type="text"]').click(function() {  
        var sd = $(this).attr('placeholder');  
        $('label[for^=sd]').fadeIn();  
    });  
});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This works:

```
$('label[for^="' + sd + '"]').fadeIn();
```

Try it http://jsfiddle.net/hwJy8/

Answer (score 19):

You are selecting with the literal string "sd", not the value of your variable. Try this:

```
var sd = $(this).attr('placeholder');
$('label[for^="' + sd + '"]').fadeIn();
```

Answer (score 3):

You probably want:

```
$('label[for^="' + sd + '"]').fadeIn();
```

You're also not using `<label for="...">` correctly <sup>[[doc]](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/label)</sup>. The `for` attribute of a `<label>` should reference the `<input>`'s `id` attribute and not its `placeholder` attribute. You'd probably be interested in changing your code to:

```
<label for="name">First Name</label>
```

and

```
var id = $(this).attr('id');
$('label[for^="' + id + '"]').fadeIn();
```

Comment: @PiTheNumber that's because he's using "for" attribute wrong - he should change his markup to this:
            <input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="First Name" />
            <label for="name">First Name </label>

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to have an input placeholder dissapear when the user is focused on it, and than re-appear when they remove focus this worked well form me.

```
  $('#inputRanges input').on('focus', function(){
                if(!$(this).data('placeholder')){
                    $(this).data('placeholder', $(this).attr('placeholder'));
                }
                $(this).attr('placeholder', "");
            }).on('focusout', function(){
                if($(this).val()==""){
                    $(this).attr('placeholder', $(this).data('placeholder'));
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess your selector string for the label is wrong`$('label[for="'+sd+'"]').fadeIn();`

Answer (score 0):

If the label will always be right next to the input (as the CSS selector shows) you could try:

```
$(function(){
    $(":text").bind("focus", function(){
        $(this).next().fadeIn();
    });
});
```

and skip the placeholder attribute altogether. Also binding to "focus" might be better than "click"

Comment: I agree with your second statement about using `focus`, but not your first. Using `.next()` (in this case) is bound to cause a bug when the next developer comes along and moves the markup around.

Comment: That's true. But since the selector "input+label" was being used that's why I went for it.